# [Shell]Escaping of characters

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I try to execute a simple SQL query in a shell script but I had trouble because of the escape of characters

Here is the problem line

```
#!/bin/sh
su -l mysql -c 'mysql -h XXX.XXX.XX.XXX -uuser -padmin -D testBD -e "SELECT CASE MODE WHEN 0 THEN \'choix1\' WHEN 1 THEN \'choix2\' WHEN 2 THEN \'choix3\' END , count( * ) FROM city GROUP BY name" > /kbd/testSelect'
```

I have tested this, but I get errors of escaping character that I don t know how to solve
Thank you very much

```
line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/kbd/test.sh: line 4: ` su -l mysql -c 'mysql -h XXX.XXX.XX.XXX -uuser -padmin -D testBD -e "SELECT CASE MODE WHEN 0 THEN \'choix1\' WHEN 1 THEN \'choix2\' WHEN 2 THEN \'choix3\' END , count( * ) FROM city GROUP BY name" > /kbd/testSelect''
```

Comment: @Tichodrama Thanks for your reply , it ' s posted

Comment: Assuming the SQL query is correct how about this : `su -l mysql -c "mysql -h XXX.XXX.XX.XXX -uuser -padmin -D testBD -e \"SELECT CASE MODE WHEN 0 THEN 'choix1' WHEN 1 THEN 'choix2' WHEN 2 THEN 'choix3' END , count( * ) FROM city GROUP BY name\" > /kbd/testSelect"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to put the command you want to execute in a separate script:

```
#!/bin/sh
mysql -h XXX.XXX.XX.XXX -uuser -padmin -D testBD -e "SELECT CASE MODE WHEN 0 THEN 'choix1' WHEN 1 THEN 'choix2' WHEN 2 THEN 'choix3' END , count( * ) FROM city GROUP BY name" > /kbd/testSelect
```

Then call that script from your original script:

```
#!/bin/sh
su -l mysql -c "/path/to/my_new_script.sh"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I as forced to do everything in one file.
But I keep your solution by my side
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I looks like the problem is not caused by shell escaping but by MySQL `SELECT` syntax. Does you query work in the standalone MySQL client?

Comment: @Tichodrama Yep, no problem in MySQL client , and if i try only this : mysql -h XXX.XXX.XX.XXX -uuser -padmin -D testBD -e "SELECT CASE MODE WHEN 0 THEN 'choix1' WHEN 1 THEN 'choix2' WHEN 2 THEN 'choix3' END , count( * ) FROM city GROUP BY name" > /kbd/testSelect , it work perfectly :p